# I need to understand why delegation in Objective-C is so important, what makes it so special?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, delegation

So I've read about delegate explanation and practices a lot, but I still seem to not get it, I have specific questions and I would love to have some insightful simple answers.

1. Why use delegate over instance method? In `UIAlertView` why not just make `– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` an instance method that will be called on my `UIAlertView` instance?
2. What is the delegate property? why do I have to make delegate property and define it with that weird syntax `@property (nonatomic, strong) id <ClassesDelegate> delegate`
3. Is delegate and protocol are two faces for a coin?
4. When do I know I should implement delegate in my app instead of direct calling?
5. Is delegate used as much and as important in Swift?
6. What gets called first and why? The method in the class who made himself a delegate? or the delegate method itself in class where it is declared?

Thank you for taking the time to go through this, I am desperately looking for a clear and helpful answers to my questions, feel free to give example or cover some related topic!

Comment: Delegation is a design pattern. It can be implemented in any language. It is not specific to Objective-C.

Comment: Delegation is awesome, and delegates should not be `strong`, they should be `weak`.

Comment: @maddy Caution history: While this is true around 1993 there was a debate about the direction of C++ mainly between Cargile and Stroustrup (guess who won) about two main issues. 1. Multiple Inherence 2. Delegation. Cargile wanted it to be a first class citizen of C++. Stroustrup argued that he had never seen an usage of Delegation that was not either a toy or convoluted and difficult to understand.

Comment: I come from a Windows PC C++ background and so I think of Objective-C's Delegation the same way I think of Window's Callbacks.  

The underlying OS in both environments needs a way to 'call you back' at times and you need to provide the OS informations about where you'd like to be called back. 

Try thinking about it that way and see if it helps.  I was confused at first because the word 'Delegation' seemed to be doing something mysterious that I didn't get.

Comment: @Gallymon I understand the concept, I don't understand its technical implementation clearly.

Comment: Emad, I'm not sure I understand.   When a particular controller like the ImagePicker is instantiated, it will typically have events it wants to inform you of asynchronously.  You have to tell it where you are going to place the routines it will call to inform you that these events have occurred and to pass you relevant data.  

Some folks might like to place their delegate code someplace else other than 'self' so you have the option to tell the OS where you are going to place the delegate routines.

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of delegation is Dependency Inversion.

Usually code has a compile-time dependency in the same direction of the run-time calling dependency. If this was the case the `UITableview` class would have a compile-time dependence on our code since it calls our code. By using delegation this is inverted, our code has a compile-time dependency on the `UITableview` class but the `UITableview` class calls our code at run-time.

There is a cost involved: we need to set the delegate and UITableview has to check at run-time that the delegate method is implemented.

Note: When I say `UITableview` I am including `UITableviewDelegate` and `UITableviewDatasource`.

See: [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and [Clean Code, Episode 13](http://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-13/show).

Comment: I am doing my best to grasp what you just said.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a real life example can better describe what's different in the delegation design pattern.

Suppose you open a new business, and you have an accountant to take care of the bureaucratic stuffs.

**Scenario #1**

You go to his office, and give him the information he needs:

- the company name
- the company # number/id
- the number of employees
- the email address
- the street address
- etc.

Then the accountant will store the data somewhere, and will probably tell you **"don't forget to call me if there's any change"**.

Tomorrow you hire a new employee, but forget to notify your accountant. He will still use the original outdated data you provided him.

**Scenario #2**

Using the delegation pattern, you go to your accountant, and you provide him your phone number (the delegate), and nothing else.

Later, he'll call you, asking: what's the business name?

Later, he'll call you, asking: how many employees do you have?

Later, he'll call you, asking: what's your company address?

The day after you hire a new employee.

2 days later, he'll call you asking: how many employee do you have?

In the delegation model (scenario #2), you see that your accountant will always have on demand up-to-date data, because he will call you every time he needs data. That's what "don't call me, I'll call you" means when talking of inversion of control (from the accountant perspective).

Transposing that in development, for example to populate a table you have 2 options:

- instantiate a table control, pass all the data (list of items to display), then ask the table to render itself
- instantiate a table control, give it a pointer to a delegate, and let it call the delegate when it needs to know:

  - the number of rows in the table
  - the data to display on row no. n
  - the height the row no. n should have
  - etc.
    but also when:
  - the row no. n has been tapped
  - the header has been tapped
  - etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't feel bad that all if stuff isn't clear yet. This is a good example of something that seems tricky at first, but just takes time really click. That will happen before you know it :-). I'll try and answer each of your points above:

1) Think of it this way - the way UIAlertView works now, it allows Apple to “delegate” the implementation of the alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: to you. If this was an instance method of UIAlertView, it would be the same implementation for everyone. To customize the implementation would then require subclassing - an often over relied upon design pattern. Apple tends to go with composition over inheritance in their frameworks and this is an example of that. You can read more on that concept here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

2) The delegate property is a reference to the object which implements the delegation methods and whichs should be used to “delegate” those tasks to. The weird syntax just means this - a property that holds a reference to an object that adheres to the  protocol.

3) Not quite - delegation leverages protocols as a means for it’s implementation. In the example above, the  is this the name of a protocol that an object which can be considered a delegate for that class must adhere to. It is inside that protocol that the methods for which a delegate of that class must implement are defined. You can also have optional protocol methods but that’s a different topic.

4) If I understand the question correctly, I think a good sign that you may want a delegate to be implemented instead of simply adding instance methods to your object is when you think that you may want the implementation of those methods to be easily swapped out or changed. When the implementation of those methods changes considerably based on where/how the functionality your building is being used

5) Absolutely! Objective-C and Swift are programming languages and the delegation pattern is an example of a design pattern. In general design patterns are hoziontal concepts that transcend across the verticals of programming languages.

6) I’m not sure I understand you exactly but I think there’s a bit of misunderstanding in the question - the method does not get called twice. The method declared in the delegate protocol is called once - typically from the class that contains the delegate property. The class calls the delegates implementation of that property via something like:

[self.delegate someMethodThatMyDelegateImplemented];

I hope some of this helped!

Comment: Thank for your explanation. However, I am still not sure if I got the delegate property part, can you try to explain it in another way?

Comment: Also, can I use delegation pattern without protocol? how would that look like?

Comment: How come I deleted the delegate from my header and the app still works, it only warns me? how come i was able to use protocol method from the delegator class without saying i conform to that delegate, and it works?
`Assigning to 'id<ClassesDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong'`

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometimes you want your UIAlertView to work different in different contexts. If you set your custom UIAlertView to be delegate of itself it has to provide all those contexts (a lot of if/else statements). You can also set seperate delegate for each context.
2. This way you say to your compiler that every class (id) which implements protocol ClassesDelegate can be set to this property. As a side note it should usually be `weak` instead of `strong` to not introduce reference cycle (class A holds B, and B holds A)
3. Protocol (interface in other languages) is used to define set of methods which should be implemented by class. If class conforms to the protocol you can call this methods without knowledge of the specific class. Delegate is pattern in which class A delegates some work to class B (e.g. abstract printer delegates his work real printer)
4. When you need few different behaviours which depends on context (e.g. `ContactsViewController` needs to refresh his list when download is finished, but `SingleContactViewController` needs to reload image, labels etc.)
5. It is one of the most fundamental patterns in programming, so yes.
6. It's the same method

Comment: Note: "methods which are required" But not all delegate methods are required in Apple's implementation of the delegate pattern.

Comment: Thank you, have some bits unclear, will work on it more.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a method to UIAlertView, because you don't have the source code. You'd have to subclass UIAlertView. But since you have more than one use of UIAlertView, You'd need several subclasses. That's very inconvenient.

Now let's say you use a library that subclasses UIAlertView, giving more functionality. That's trouble, because now you need to subclass this subclass instead of UIAlertView.

Now let's say that library uses different subclasses of UIAlertview, depending on whether you run on iOS 7 or 8, and UIAlertview unchanged on iOS 6. You're in trouble. Your subclassing pattern breaks down.

Instead, you create a delegate doing all the things specific to one UIAlertview. That delegate will work with the library just fine. Instead of subclassing a huge and complicated class, you write a very simple class. Most likely the code using the UIAlertview knows exactly what the delegate should be doing, so you can keep that code together.

Comment: sorry I may have said it in a bad way, but I meant why didn't apple for example make `UIAlerView` have instance method to handle the buttons actions etc.

And apply that for me, when I decide to make a delegate, why not just do what i want to achieve by importing that class and use instance/class methods and direct calling?